# How to: Two elements with equal width when stacked vertically, otherwise auto width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create two buttons that have auto width when placed side by side, but have equal width when stacked above and below (due to there not being enough horizontal space to fit them side by side). I'd like to do this with **CSS only** before I have to resort to using a ***big JavaScript mallet***.

The following works side by side:

```css
.flex {
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

button {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <button class="flex-item">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</button>
  <button class="flex-item">two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two</button>
</div>
```

Which gives:

[image: side by side auto widths]

However when wrapping they take up 100% of the width rather than the width of the largest button:

[image: wrapping with incorrect width of 100%]

The following shows what I'm after when wrapping (swapping to flex-direction: column)

[image: desired layout when wrapping]

Is there a way for me to achieve this with CSS? (it doesn't have to be a flexbox based solution)

**Big JavaScript Mallet**

If anyone's interested in the JavaScript Mallet:

**CSS**

```
.flex {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const setButtonWidths = () => {
  const button1 = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-item')[0]
  const button2 = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-item')[1]
  button1.style.width = ''
  button2.style.width = ''
  const bounds1 = button1.getBoundingClientRect()
  const bounds2 = button2.getBoundingClientRect()
  const wrapping = bounds1.top !== bounds2.top
  if (wrapping) {
    const maxWidth = Math.max(bounds1.width, bounds2.width)
    button1.style.width = `${maxWidth}px`
    button2.style.width = `${maxWidth}px`
  } 
}

setButtonWidths()
window.addEventListener('resize', setButtonWidths)
```

Comment: No I do not believe so. CSS can't detect wrapping/overflow so it would have no way of determining *when* there is not enough room.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, good to know I'm not going crazy :-) JavaScript mallet it is!

Answer (score 0):

It could kinda work if you can use media queries...

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex">
  <button class="flex-item">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</button>
  <button class="flex-item">two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: min-content; /* Will take up the closest width to the smallest child width i.e. button 1 */ 
}

.flex-item {
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents line breaks */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 1270px) {
  .flex {
    width: unset; /* Removes initial width setting on the parent after breakpoint*/
  }

  .flex-item {
    flex-grow: unset; /* Prevents growth of children after breakpoint */
  }
  
}
```

Since CSS has no way of detecting the widths of the flex-items, we'll have to specify an appropriate breakpoint we want wrapping to begin or end. With a breakpoint, we can now set breakpoint-dependent width and flex properties on the parent and children respectively.

For this to work, we'll need to prevent line breaks in the buttons `white-space: nowrap;` but this might need to be reset (with another breakpoint) to allow wrapping on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: my problem can't be solved with media queries. the length of the text inside the buttons is variable, so e.g. on small screens if 2 buttons fit side by side i want them to have their original width, however if there isn't space due to the text inside the buttons being longer, then i want them to stack above and below but have equal width.

Comment: Alright, then you'll have to use Javascript to get the widths of the buttons, then the rest can be done in CSS as shown in the answer as we're basically replacing the media query with the Javascript width detection. Let me know if you'd want to see an implementation of this.